# How to focus object in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, focus

I want to bring focus to a given object present in a web page using selenium web driver. Tried with Action class but it doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this? I am using selenium web driver with java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to focus an element in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337353/correct-way-to-focus-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 4):

### HTMLElement.focus()

The [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) method sets focus on the desired element, if it can be focused. The focused element is the element which can receive the keyboard and similar events by default.

---

### This usecase

Generally, invoking `click()` will set the focus on the desired element.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector")).click();
```

Ideally, you should induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` while invoking the `click()` to set the focus as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector"))).click();
```

At times, you may need to use `moveToElement()` method from [Actions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) *Class* inconjunction with `click()` to set the focus as follows:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

You can also use the [`executeScript()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from [JavascriptExecutor](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) *Interface* to set the focus as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('element_ID').focus();");
```

But in this case, you need to ensure that the specific window is focused and to achive that you can use the following line of code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```