# How to fix selenium "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I need to fix my script I'm still geting the error:

```
no such element found
```

Part of my code is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://bulksmsplans.com/register")
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
country_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country_id")
select_object = Select(country_input)
select_object.select_by_value(country_id)
# find password input field and insert password as well
name_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "name")
time.sleep(2)
name_input.send_keys(name)
email_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
time.sleep(2)
email_input.send_keys(email)
phone_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "phone")
phone_input.send_keys(phone)
time.sleep(2) 
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()  
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")
button.click();
```

All working, but the last step when the bot must to click on green button "Create Account", nope...

What is wrong on this line:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While interacting with the [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502835/7429447) you have switched to the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447).

Next, to click on the element <kbd>Create Account</kbd> you have to shift *Selenium*'s [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) back to the **default** content (or parent_frame) using either of the following lines of code:

- Using *`default_content()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  ```
- Using *`parent_frame()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
  ```

Comment: @MassimoB. Glad to be able to help you out.

Comment: of course, 3 days i have try it.... so many many thanks !!!