# VBA selenium scroll windows to element point

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In VBA I need to move in Selenium viewport to the element to be clickable. I tried code below ;

```
.Mouse.MoveTo(.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a"),13,13) 'error Expeted = sign
.Actions.MoveToElement (.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a")) 'ineffective screen does not scroll down. Note: Windos is set to Maximize
```

the code is added but does not work, I could not add to the comment section

```
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a").Click
.Actions.MoveToElement(.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a")).Perform
.Actions.MoveToElement(.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a")).Perform
.Actions.MoveByOffset(300, 300).Perform
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a").Click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move Selenium's [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) to the element you can use either of the following lines of code:

```
.Actions.MoveToElement(.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a")).Perform
```

or

```
.Actions.MoveToElement(.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a"), 13, 13).Perform
```

Comment: first one without result, the second one gives an error 'Wrong number of element'. I changed to .Actions.MoveByOffset()..same result with same error

Comment: I tried to write similar java code from link you shared, but gives an error expected = sign.  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_cssSelector"))).click();
.WaitForScript(browser, .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""main-content""]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/div/a").Click,2000)

Comment: Java code won't suit VB environment.  Let me check the code implementation.

Comment: I found somthing like below. It resolves partially. But I need, movetoelement           Dim ks As Selenium.Keys
    Set ks = New Selenium.Keys    .SendKeys ks.PageDown