# Python-Selenium: How to 'switch_to.active_element' to an input element inside a shadow dom?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, shadow-dom, browser-automation

I am writing a QA automation script using Python and Selenium.

I want to check if the input is already focused when the webpage is rendered.
My problem is that I can't find a way to get the currently focused input that is inside the shadow dom.

HTML doc looks like this:

```
<div>
  #shadow-root
    # this input element is already focused when the page is rendered
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```

I've tried `driver.switch_to.active_element` but it always returns None, probably because it can't access shadow dom.

I hope anyone knows another way to get the currently focused input element inside a shadow dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the webpage is rendered though you observe that the `<input>` is already [focused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) but [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447)'s focus is at the *Top Level Browsing Context*.

So to identify the `<input>` element you need to bring Selenium's focus within the [**shadow-root**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447) first.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [PrintText-How to extract info within a #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)