# How to get URL of currently open web browser tab

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I want to be able to grab the url of the currently open tab in a web browser. I can do this with Selenium but it requires that the web browser is opened with Selenium's webdriver. I instead want to be able to run this script with a Firefox or Chrome window already open, and have it return the url of the currently open tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the URL of the active Google Chrome tab in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645123/how-do-i-get-the-url-of-the-active-google-chrome-tab-in-windows)

Comment: @venky__ This is exactly what I'm trying to do but I want to be able to do it for a variety of browsers, any tips on how to get this working for Firefox and Edge?

Comment: @venky__ Also looking at the other answers and comments on that link it seems that the solution no longer works

Comment: @retsek680 , did you find any solution for this? I was also looking for this.